# Show address bar w. full path in Nautilus instead of breadcrumbs bar

Tags: gnome, gui, nautilus

Unfortunately, Gnome's [nautilus](/questions/tagged/nautilus) address bar is not showing the **full path** in its top bar. How can I change this behavior?

I'm looking for a solution to display a editable `text field` instead, like in the good old days.

[image]

Answer (score 88):

Press <kbd>Ctl</kbd> and while holding it down, press <kbd>L</kbd>.

To return to the original breadcrumb view, make sure that the editable text area has the focus then press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

To make it permanent (i.e. to always use location entry) run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences always-use-location-entry true
```

or

```
dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/always-use-location-entry true
```

Same commands to revert to breadcrumbs (just replace `true` with `false`).

Comment: Awesome, the `dconf` command worked for me, I'm using Unity on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The dconf command worked for me as well, on Redhat.

Comment: this is a great answer. But come on Nautilus, this is esoteric just for the sake of it. ...add a toggle button!

Comment: (and i know a little off topic but Nautilus adding "right click over menu breadcrumbs=> copy path to "selected breadcrumb depth" menu option I think would a sensible feature also)  :)

Comment: How to do it for Open/Save dialogs?

Comment: This solution works, but it SELECTS the path text when nautilus opens. This is awkward. Anyone know if this is fixable?

Comment: Press the cursor left/right key? (I can't test because I don't have access at the moment)

Comment: Wow, it's silly this isn't in the Nautilus preferences.