# Show all Breadcrumbs in Nautilus

Tags: gnome3, nautilus, suse

is there an option to always display the full path as breadcrumbs in Nautilus (full path in text is possible via [editing dconf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154106/show-address-bar-w-full-path-in-nautilus-instead-of-breadcrumbs-bar?newreg=65f7adca81834cf98fdc7eb1a1f2bff1)). I think this is the default in Ubuntu, but I am using SLES here.

[image: Nautilus with one Breadcrumb]

[image: Nautilus with 2 Breadcrumbs (only like this in home folder)]